# Loop in elixir with delay interval

Tags: elixir

I have the following code in elixir, where I want to call a function - parseCsvFiles in a loop:

```
def loopParseFiles do
    spawn(Parse_Csv,:parseCsvFiles,[self])
    receive do
        {:parse_complete} -> loopParseFiles
        after
         20000 -> loopParseFiles
    end
end
```

In the above code, I want to set a delay such that, the loopParseFiles function is called back after 20000 miliseconds or after :parse_complete is received - **whichever is more**.

TIA :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to always wait for at least 20 seconds, and then wait until `:parse_complete` is received?  You can do it like this:

```
def loopParseFiles do
    spawn(Parse_Csv,:parseCsvFiles,[self])
    :timer.sleep 20000
    receive do
        {:parse_complete} -> loopParseFiles
    end
end
```

Even if the `:parse_complete` message arrives during the call to `:timer.sleep`, it will still be waiting in the mailbox once the `receive` expression is ready to pick it up.

Comment: Thanks. But what about "after"? If I don't receive a :parse_complete at all and "after" is lesser than :timer.sleep, would it still work? or do I have to keep the value of "after" more than 20000 (that is the value of :timer.sleep)?

Comment: You could keep the `after`, specifying the additional time you want to wait after waiting 20000 milliseconds in `:timer:sleep`. For example, if you use `after 5000`, the total time waited will be 25000 milliseconds if the `:parse_complete` message doesn't arrive.